# How to draw an image into a div via php

Tags: php, html, image, path

I have two include files:

1.draw_images.php

```
<?
    function practice_area_img($img_path)
    {
        $items = "";
        $files = glob($img_path . "/*.*");
        for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
        {
            $num = $files[$i];

            $items .= <<<HTML

            <div class="item">                      
                <img src="$num" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>

    HTML;
        }
        return $items;
    }
?>
```

The above code snippet goes through a folder and draws all the images therein into stylized `div` tags.

Please note here that I get the **div** `blog-slider` drawn, but the images fail. The image path is of this kind:

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project/images/my_pic.jpg
```

2.definitions.php

```
<?php

    $rev_args['images_path'] = dirname(__FILE__) . '/images';

?>
```

I call them as follows:

```
<?php

    include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/definitions.php');
    include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/draw_images.php');

    <div id="blog-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <?= practice_area_img($rev_args['images_path']); ?>
    </div>
```

How can I go about getting the image drawn?

**UPDATE**

Please nothe that `<?= $num; ?>` prints a something like `/opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project/images/my_pic.jpg`

so:

```
<img src="$num" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

is actually :

```
<img src="/opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project/images/my_pic.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the source of the generated html, the only thing I can see, is that the image paths are probably wrong.

You display the image using:

```
<img src="$num" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

However, you look in the `images/` directory of the script path to get them, so instead of just echoing the filenames, you should probably use something like:

```
<img src="images/$num" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

**Edit:** Based on your comment, you would need something like:

```
$num = basename($files[$i]);

...

<img src="images/$num" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jeroen. Please nothe that <?= $num; ?> prints a something like `/opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project/images/my_pic.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

It is a absolute path problem in your img tag

```
<?
    function practice_area_img($img_path)
    {
        $items = "";
        $files = glob($img_path . "/*.*");
        for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
        {
            $num = $files[$i];
            // remove absolute path
            $relPath = str_replace(dirname(__FILE__)."/", "", $num);
            $items .= <<<HTML

            <div class="item">                      
                <img src="$relPath" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>

    HTML;
        }
        return $items;
    }
?>
```

This will produce:

```
<img src="images/my_pic.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

which it will search the image under your server you can put in front of it 
http(s)://localhost  (servername) if you want to.